# Dynamic choices WTForms Flask SelectField

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to pass userID variable to WTForms with FlaskForms. First I'll show code that works fine and then what I need to modify(that the part I don't know how). I'm adding new Name associated with some group.

**FlaskForm model:**

```
class AddName(FlaskForm):
    name =StringField('Device name', validators=[InputRequired(),Length(min=4, max=30)])
    groupID = SelectField('Payload Type', choices=[(1,"Group1"),(2,"Group2")], validators=[InputRequired])
```

**View model:**

```
@app.route('/dashboard/addname', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def addname():
    form=AddName()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name=Name(form.name.data,form.groupID.data)
        db.session.add(name)
        db.session.commit()
        return "New name added"
```

**Template:**

```
              <form method="POST" action="/dashboard/addname">
                  <h2>Add name</h2>
                  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                  {{ wtf.form_field(form.name) }}
                  {{ wtf.form_field(form.groupID) }}
                  <button type="submit">Add name</button>
              </form>
```

I see correct list in dropdown, and on submit gives me correct numbers.

**Task:** I need to pass different list based on **current_user.userID**.
I'm forming list using SQLAlchemy, by making query from table from DB, so My **Flask view is:**

```
@app.route('/dashboard/addname', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def addname():
    available_groups=db.session.query(Groups).filter(Groups.userID == currend_user.userID).all()
    #Now forming the list of tuples, so it's ok for SelectField
    groups_list=[(i.groupID, i.groupName) for i in available_groups]
    form=AddName()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name=Name(form.name.data,form.groupID.data)
        db.session.add(name)
        db.session.commit()
        return "New name added"
```

1. How can i pass my **groups_list** to the form? I tried to implement forming procedure in the FlaskForm model, but it doesn't see current_user object
2. Do I need to transform groupID to *string* and then back to *int* when I need to pass it to the SelectField like tuples?

Comment: is there any better way to do this? like using meta class or something ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The main idea here is to assign the choices list to the field after instantiation. To do so you need to use argument `coerce=int`. The coerce keyword arg to SelectField says that we use int() to coerce form data. The default coerce is unicode().

**Correct FormModel:**

```
class AddName(FlaskForm):
    name =StringField('Device name', validators=[InputRequired(),Length(min=4, max=30)])
    groupID = SelectField('Payload Type', coerce=int, validators=[InputRequired])
```

**Correct View:**

```
@app.route('/dashboard/addname', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def addname():
    available_groups=db.session.query(Groups).filter(Groups.userID == currend_user.userID).all()
    #Now forming the list of tuples for SelectField
    groups_list=[(i.groupID, i.groupName) for i in available_groups]
    form=AddName()
    #passing group_list to the form
    form.groupID.choices = groups_list
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name=Name(form.name.data,form.groupID.data)
        db.session.add(name)
        db.session.commit()
        return "New name added"
```