# How to make a dynamic RadioField

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I want to make an exam form with multiple options.
How to avoid writing the radioField manually in the form class, the radioField are repeated *N* times

[image]

views.py

```
@app.route("/exams", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def exams():
    radios = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #exam_answers_form = forms.(request.form)
        class NForm(forms.ExamAnswersForm):
            pass
        n = NForm()
        datos = Questions.query.add_columns('question').filter_by(modules_id=5).all()

        for name in datos:
            setattr(n, 'question', RadioField(name, choices=[('value','descriptions'),('value_two','whatever')]))
            n.question.append()
        x = n        
        return render_template('exams/exams_answers.html', form=x )
    return render_template('exams/exams.html')
```

forms.py

```
class ExamAnswersForm(Form):
    question = RadioField(choices=[()])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic choices WTForms Flask SelectField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46921823/dynamic-choices-wtforms-flask-selectfield)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a dynamic form like this, assuming you know how to query you database to return data in a format where you can adjust the below code to work for you:

```
class ExamAnswersForm(Form):
    # get static data from database
    data = {'q_1': ('Is FEAR a good book?', (1, 'Yes'), (0, 'No')),
            'q_2': ('Is the Earth flat?', (0, 'Yes'), (1, 'No'))} 
    for label in data.keys():
        vars()[label] = RadioField(data[label][0], choices=[data[label][1], data[label][2]])
```

If you want to make this more dynamic you can create a method that returns an initialised form:

```
def exam_answers_form(*args, **kwargs):
    # do something with *args and **kwargs to get dynamic data from database
    data = {'q_1': ('Is FEAR a good book?', (1, 'Yes'), (0, 'No')),
            'q_2': ('Is the Earth flat?', (0, 'Yes'), (1, 'No'))}
    class ExamAnswersForm(Form):
        pass
    for label in data.keys():
        setattr(ExamAnswersForm, label, RadioField(data[label][0], choices=[data[label][1], data[label][2]]))
    return ExamAnswersForm()
```

Comment: I used this solution and it worked for me. I didn't use the setattr() function. Instead, what worked for me was when passed all the RadioField() arguments as keyword arguments rather than a mix of positional and keyword arguments.