# Dynamically assign choices in an selectfield of WTForm using a FieldList

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

similar to this question:
[Dynamic choices WTForms Flask SelectField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46921823/dynamic-choices-wtforms-flask-selectfield)

In my flask app I have a WTForm with several selectfields. I would like to dynamically assign the number of the selectfields and the choices of the selectfields.

```
class FormEntry(FlaskForm):
        selectfield = SelectField('Name', coerce=int, choices=[('1', 'default_choice1'), ('2', 'default_choice2')])


class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    form_entries = FieldList(FormField(FormEntry), min_entries=1)
```

An instance of a FormEntry is created and the choices are assigned:

```
my_entry = FormEntry()
my_entry.selectfield.choices =[('3', 'mychoice3'), ('4', 'mychoice4')]
```

However, when I create an instance of the Form with this entry, the choices are not my chosen choices but the default ones:

```
form_entries = [my_entry, my_entry]
form = MyForm(form_entries=form_entries)
for entry in form.form_entries:
    print(entry.selectfield.choices)
```

Print Output:

```
[('1', 'default_choice1'), ('2', 'default_choice2')]
[('1', 'default_choice1'), ('2', 'default_choice2')]
```

What went wrong and how can I assign the choices correctly?

Comment: The suggested duplicate question is incorrect; it is not a duplicate.  I also had this issue and found this post useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields.html#wtforms.fields.SelectField

From the documentation (emphasis mine)

> Note that the **choices keyword is only evaluated once**, so if you want to make a dynamic drop-down list, you’ll want to assign the choices list to the field **after** instantiation. Any inputted choices which are not in the given choices list will cause validation on the field to fail.

i.e don't have `selectfield = SelectField('Name', coerce=int, choices=[('1', 'default_choice1'), ('2', 'default_choice2')]`
use `selectfield = SelectField('Name', coerce=int)` instead.

Comment: Thanks. But If I don't provide default values for the choices, I get "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable".

Comment: Are you still setting the choices via `.choices` or how though davidism suggests in his link to his own answer (though before `validate_on_submit`)?

Comment: So far, still setting the choices via '.choices'. If I then remove the default choices in the constructor, the above print output becomes : None, None.

Comment: a few posts on SO I've seen suggest doing `form = MyForm()` then `form.form_entries[0].selectfield.choices = whatever`

Comment: What worked for me in the end is very similar to your last comment: `form = MyForm({})` then `form.form_entries[0].selectfield.choices = whatever`. So I accept the answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: However, I still do not understand why the code in my question does not work.