# Python - call function inside class function

Tags: python

I have a class that runs multiple functions. One of them is drawing an object on the sceen. I have another function that updates the state of the object, and based on the modified state, I have to change the color of the object. How can I call the function that draws the shape inside the function that updates the state. The code looks like this:

```
 class TrackCircuit:
     def __init__(self, id, name, state):
         self.id = id
         self.name = name
         self.state = state

     def draw(self, pos_x, pos_y, pos_end):
         self.pos_x = pos_x
         self.pos_y = pos_y
         self.pos_end = pos_end
         label_root_x = (pos_x + pos_end) / 2
         label_root_y = offset_top + offset_label
         global tc_width

         if self.state == "undefined":
             tc_color = color_undefined
         elif self.state == "occupied":
             tc_color = color_occupied

         canvas.create_line(pos_x, pos_y, pos_end, pos_y, width=tc_width, fill=tc_color)
         tc_label = Label(root, text="121", font = label_font, bg = label_background, fg = label_color)
         tc_label.place(x=label_root_x, y=label_root_y, anchor=CENTER)

     def update_state(self, state):
         self.state = state
```

I need to run `draw()` when state is modified through `update_state()`.

Comment: So you want to call `self.draw()` inside `update_state`?

Comment: You have to use the `self` parameter, which refers on the object.
By calling self.ANY_METHOD() you call the method ANY_METHOD. So in your case you have to use `self.draw()` inside of the `update_state` method.

Comment: Do you mean call it inside `update_state` ? Call it as you would normally, `self.draw()`

Answer (score 3):

`self` it's the current instance, so you can call on it every method and access every attributes.

Therefore you simply need to call:

```py
self.draw()
```

So the code becames:

```py
def update_state(self, state):
    self.state = state
    self.draw()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call a method of the class via `self` like this:

```py
class TrackCircuit:
    def __init__(self, id, name, state):
        # your code

    def draw(self, pos_x, pos_y, pos_end):
        # your code

    def update_state(self, state):
        self.state = state
        self.draw(....)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a function to dinamically assign choices in an selectfield of WTForm you must do that outside the Class. Find out on [Dynamically assign choices in an selectfield of WTForm using a FieldList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56199193/dynamically-assign-choices-in-an-selectfield-of-wtform-using-a-fieldlist)