# WTForms / SQLAlchemy - Can you concatenate display values in SelectField or QuerySelectField

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, python-3.7, wtforms

Is is possible to have a WTForm in which a drop down selection box (SelectField or QuerySelectField) displays a concatentated display value?

For example, your database may contain:

```
ID=1, FirstName=John, LastName=Smith
ID=2, FirstName=Kim, LastName=Johnson
```

so the generated HTML code would be something like:

```
<select name="userid">
    <option value="1">John Smith</option>
    <option value="2">Kim Johnson</option>
</select>
```

The display value is the concatenated value of FirstName + LastName. The unique identifier in the database will be the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a dynamically set SelectField:

```
form.userid.choices = [(item.id, item.firstname+' '+item.lastname) for item in 
session.query(ModelName).all()]
```

Comment: Had to tweak it slightly to get it to work in my code. But your suggestion worked for me. Thank you. I was originally trying to use the QuerySelectField but that led to some bizarre behaviour - which I still cannot explain.

Comment: This also helped with the detail. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46921823/dynamic-choices-wtforms-flask-selectfield