# flask WTForm: "working outside of application context"

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to extract the values of a Select field, from a JSON file that houses the translations. The problem is caused by the get_locale() function, which can only be called within 'context.'

This is the form select-field:

```
brand = SelectField(choices=generate_brands(get_locale()),validators=[Optional()])
```

is there a way to load this specific field only when called inside of a view when the request variable is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I well understood, you want to populate the SelectField depending of the language of the user. There are several ways to have dynamic SelectField, see Oleg's answer for a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48236887/11405279

Comment: Creating a request context does not solve the problem here, as in that case, the get_locale() function will return None meaning it will return the default locale.

Comment: do you know of a way to lazyload a single field or the whole form if the former is not available? @JBLaf

Comment: I changed my answer, as I first misunderstood what was wanted. Some good keywords to google what you want are:  dynamic SelectField