# Flask: How do I get an object's primary key from a QuerySelectField?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to get the id from an object that is trapped in a self-referential relationship. I believe my definition of the relationship may be limiting its function, or perhaps I'm projecting. I've tried every related SO solution I could find to no avail. Mainly, the `form.parent_id.data.parent_id` pattern I've seen on several solutions throws `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent_id'`. I'm aware that `sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: <unprintable InterfaceError object>` results from `form.parent_id.data` because QuerySelectField returns an object, not an id. I get the same error when setting `get_pk=lambda x: x.parent_id` in the form object.

#### routes.py

```
def edit_user(id):
    form = UserForm()
    user = User.query.get_or_404(id)
    selected_date_ids = []
    upcoming_dates = TestDate.query.order_by(TestDate.date).filter(TestDate.status != 'past')
    tests = sorted(set(TestDate.test for TestDate in TestDate.query.all()), reverse=True)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if request.method == "POST":
            ...
            user.tutor_id=form.tutor_id.data
            user.parent_id=form.parent_id.data
```

#### models.py

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    tutor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    students = db.relationship('User', backref=db.backref('tutor'), 
        foreign_keys=[tutor_id], remote_side=[id])
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    children = db.relationship('User', backref=db.backref('parent'), 
        foreign_keys=[parent_id], remote_side=[id])
```

#### forms.py

```
def get_tutors():
    return User.query.filter_by(role='tutor')

def get_parents():
    return User.query.filter_by(role='parent')

def full_name(User):
    return User.first_name + " " + User.last_name


class UserForm(FlaskForm):
    ...
    tutor_id = QuerySelectField('Tutor', default=1, query_factory=get_tutors, get_label=full_name, allow_blank=True)
    parent_id = QuerySelectField('Parent', query_factory=get_parents, get_label=full_name, allow_blank=True)
    is_admin = BooleanField('Admin')
    submit = SubmitField('Save')
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switching from QuerySelectField to SelectField using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48236887/3295556) to populate dynamic values, and everything became much simpler. Still not sure about my db.relationships, but they seem to be getting the job done.